# Does custom setting count against the total number of custom objects available for your organization?

Tags: limits, customsetting

The Salesforce [documentation](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=cs_limits.htm&language=en_US)has below line

> Custom settings are a type of custom object. Each custom setting
>   counts against the total number of custom objects available for your
>   organization.

I highly suspect this is not true anymore.

Is it still valid?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is still valid, have a look at the System overview area of your org and you will see there is an indicator bar (shown in screenshot) that details the information you are talking about. I can verify this org has 14 custom objects and 2 custom settings (it is a throwaway dev org of mine I use for playing around in). 16/400 is also exactly 4%.

[image]

Comment: a picture speaks a thousand (or less) words, nice!